# How to scale down an image in a flexible table cell to dimensions of window?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS table set out with divs displaying two cells in one row. Each cell has a  large image. The table should be full window size.

I want to make the large images scale down to fit side by side in the dimensions of the users window, whatever resolution that maybe. At present the images are at their full dimensions and won't scale down even if I target them directly with height: 100% width: auto and max-height: 100% max-width: auto.

Thanks very much for anyone who can help or point out the obvious.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left"><img src="http://wallpaperstate.org/wp-content/gallery/ca_home/rainbow-colors-wallpaper-wallpapers-28469135-2560-1600.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="http://wallpaperstate.org/wp-content/gallery/ca_home/new-2013-high-quality-abstract-wallpaper.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.parent > div{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.parent > .right {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: auto;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liam14000/53ySr/)

P.s Apologies for the load time of the large example images.

Comment: So you want the images to fit to user window in both height and width?

Comment: Ah, apologies. Only in height! The width does not matter. And the images are uneven proportions so the height is already larger. I have updated the JSFiddle with new images of the proper dimensions. http://jsfiddle.net/liam14000/53ySr/4/ @Jithin

Comment: Also the image dimensions need to stay even and  in proportion when resizing. So I'm guessing as the window is shrunk a gap will expand from right as the width shrinks. @Jithin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:  it's only about height so inline-block or float will be efficient :

```
html, body, .parent {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.parent {
    white-space : nowrap;
}
.parent > div {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    ;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/53ySr/6/
note the simpliest is http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vGhbf (no div.right nor div.left)

this was first version shrinking within window's width for those who are curious :
using display:table, you need table-layout to control width, that helps .
see http://jsfiddle.net/53ySr/2/ jsfiddle.net/53ySr/3/

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.parent > div{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background:#233C40;
}
img {
    width:  100%;
    height:100%;/* you can remove this */
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Apologies I forgot that I only require the height to fit in the users window. I have updated the JSFiddle with uneven images with larger height to reflect this. If you could kindly take a look. Ah, apologies. Only in height! The width does not matter. And the images are uneven proportions so the height is already larger. I have updated the JSFiddle with new images of the proper dimensions. http://jsfiddle.net/liam14000/53ySr/4/ @GCyrillus

Comment: Also the image dimensions need to stay even and  in proportion when resizing. So I'm guessing as the window is shrunk a gap will expand from right as the width shrinks. @GCyrillus

Comment: hello, oki, so to control height, inline-block (or float) will do , table will not update here : http://jsfiddle.net/53ySr/6/

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following edit to your css, It will do the trick.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: inherit;
}

.parent > div{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.parent > .right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.parent > .left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/bvbHF/